# Filter through a related model django

Tags: django, django-queryset

How can I generate a query_set through a related model?

For example, how can I do this:

```
UserProfile.objects.filter(user.is_active=True) # Can't use user.is_active to filter
```

Trivial question, trivial answer. But I'll keep it here for posterity's sake.

Comment: i am glad you did! who reads docs these days, easier to come to SO!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
UserProfile.objects.filter(user__is_active=True)
```

This is well [documented](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/topics/db/queries/#lookups-that-span-relationships) in the Django docs.

Comment: Yes, I just found it. Thanks. [Spanning Relationships](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#lookups-that-span-relationships)

Answer (score 3):

From the [Django documention](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#lookups-that-span-relationships)

> Django offers a powerful and intuitive way to "follow" relationships in lookups, taking care of the SQL JOINs for you automatically, behind the scenes. To span a relationship, just use the field name of related fields across models, separated by double underscores, until you get to the field you want.

In your example this would be:

```
 UserProfile.objects.filter(user__is_active=True)
```

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to follow a relationship is to use a simple "__".

UserProfile.objects.filter(user__is_active=True)

These can be changed together as well (ie user_*parent*_email='abc@def.com')