# Django activity stream filter Actions by foreignkey in target model

Tags: python, django, activity-streams, django-activity-stream

I would like to filter Actions for particular queryset.

To this moment I was grabbing data by generating a model stream on desired model.

```
model_stream(FillingSystem)
```

I would like to extend this functionality and have something like this

```
model_stream(FillingSystem.objects.filter(client__slug='my-slug'))
```

or

```
model_stream(FillingSystem.objects.filter(client=Client.objects.get(slug='my-slug')))
```

this model looks like this:

```
class FillingSystem(models.Model):
    client = models.ForeignKey('accounts.Client')
```

How do I filter a stream by related slug field?

Comment: This should be the answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7339580/filter-through-a-related-model-django

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems you can just [pass your filters](https://github.com/justquick/django-activity-stream/blob/8f56aad29ecccd83385ca2f12f40e2db8468619d/actstream/managers.py#L62) as `**kwargs`:

```
model_stream(FillingSystem, filling_system__client__slug='my-slug')
```

where `target` is a `GenericForeignKey` to your content (feel free to choose [from the others](https://github.com/justquick/django-activity-stream/blob/8f56aad29ecccd83385ca2f12f40e2db8468619d/actstream/models.py#L87)).

You may have to declare a reverse relation to the `Action` model:

```
from django.contrib.contenttypes.fields import GenericRelation
from actstream.models import Action

class FillingSystem(models.Model):
    client = models.ForeignKey('accounts.Client')
    stream_actions = GenericRelation(
                         Action,
                         content_type_field='target_content_type'
                         object_id_field='target_object_id'
                         related_query_name='filling_system')
```

Comment: Field 'target' does not generate an automatic reverse relation and therefore cannot be used for reverse querying. If it is a GenericForeignKey, consider adding a GenericRelation.

Comment: There seems to be still the same error
:)

    client = models.ForeignKey('accounts.Client')
    stream_actions = GenericRelation(Action)

Comment: @Efrin, sorry for that, GFK's are a bit messy. Try specifying all that stuff manually as I did in the (updated one more time) answer. Just pay attention to the changed `kwarg`.

Comment: Wow! That was awesome, thank you very much :) You saved me a lot of time! :)

Comment: This doesn't work for me, it fails with ```operator does not exist: character varying = integer
LINE 1: ... ON ("actstream_action"."action_object_object_id" = "notific...
                                                             ^
HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts.```
target_object_id uses CharField, while the key of my other model is a normal Integer. Any ideas?

Comment: Stumbling upon the same error as @graup - any suggestions?

Comment: @Hybrid I raised the issue here: https://github.com/justquick/django-activity-stream/issues/281 The author is aware of it.

Comment: I see, thank you. I ended up just creating a custom plugin for myself which accepts the object_id as a `PositiveInteger()` instead of a `CharField()` (which I don't know why the author would do in the first place)... but I assume the casting error could be fixed by simply wrapping the `object_id` with `str()` function.