# How to use django-activity-stream to Create Notificications

Tags: python, django, filter, notifications, django-activity-stream

I would like to use django-activity-stream in order to present notifications to users, but I am having a hard time doing so. From the looks of the documentation, you can only display generic actions to users, such as **all** that actions performed on a model, but I would like to filter them. For example: If `User A` posts a `Comment` on `User B`'s `Article`, I want to be able to show that notification to `User B`.

I have tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34708719/django-activity-stream-filter-actions-by-foreignkey-in-target-model) approach, but the approved solution is not working at all (although my question is basically the same).

Any suggestions?

`Django v1.9.6`
`Python v3.4.3`
`django-activity-stream v0.6.2`