# Querying through four models in Django

Tags: django, django-orm

I have a data model similar to this (simplified):

```
class Mobility(models.Model):
    pass

class Transfer(models.Model):
    mobility = models.ForeignKey(Mobility)

class Organism(models.Model):
    pass

class TransferLine(models.Model):
    transfer = models.ForeignKey(Transfer)
    organism = models.ForeignKey(Organism)
```

I have an instance of `Mobility` and an instance of `Organism`, and I'd like to get all the `TransferLine` instances that are related to both (to the `Organism` directly, and to the `Mobility` through the `Transfer`).

This question differs from [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7339580/filter-through-a-related-model-django) in that in my case, I need to go through two relations and there's also a compound condition.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Filter through a related model django](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7339580/filter-through-a-related-model-django)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use the [double-underscore notation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/queries/#lookups-that-span-relationships) to make lookups that span relationships. In this case, it could be done like this:

```
transfer_lines = TransferLine.objects.filter(transfer__mobility=mobility, 
                                             organism=organism)
```

Answer (score 1):

Another approach would be to use the `ForeignKey` [reverse relation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/1.9/topics/db/queries/#following-relationships-backward):

```
tlines = my_organisam.transferline_set.filter(transfer__mobility=my_mobility)
```